# Function not changing boolean from true to false

Tags: python, boolean

I'm trying to create an interactive story code for a quick thing and my boolean doesn't seem to be changing from true to false in my code.
Here it is:

```
age = input ("Type in your age")
print("You're bored during quarantine and decide to go visit a haunted house alone. You visit the house, open the door, and walk in.")
print("You are in front of a creepy door in a hallway.")
print("What do you want to do?")
action = input ("Type: in, left, or right. Then click OK or press enter")
survive = False

def survival():
  if age%2 == 0:
    survive = False
  else:
    survive = True
    
survival()

if action == "in":
  print("You choose to go in.")
  print("The room is pitch black")
  if survive == False:
    print("A monster pops out of the corner and eats you!")
  else:
    print("You turn the light on and realize that this is just an old bathroom. Gross.")
if action == "left":
  print("You choose to turn left.")
  print("A ghost appears at the end of the hall.")
  if survive == False:
    print("The ghost chases you down and haunts your soul forever!")
  else:
    print("Your eyes mistook you, it was a spiderweb.")
if action == "right":
  print("You choose to turn right")
  print("A greenish light is visible in the distance")
  if survive == False:
    print("The light gets brighter and brighter, and you realize it was the headlamp of a ghost coal miner!")
  else:
    print("You go to check out the light, turns out it's some old christmas lighting still plugged in.")
    
if survive == False:
  print("May your soul rest eternally as you join the other ghosts at the haunted house.")
else:
  print("You survived your stay at the haunted house and apparently it's just a house.")
```

You can see that I'm trying to get the age of the person, and if that divides by 2 evenly then set the survive to false. However, no matter what age you put in you still get survive = false if it's even or odd. Any ideas to what could be wrong?

Comment: because your function merel creates a local variable. You need to use `global my_variable` for an assigment to act globally. But you *shouldn't*. Instead, pass in the values that a function needs as arguments to the function, and return the values needed outside from the function. Don't use mutable, global state

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry I'm new to python, I don't quite understand. So I need to state the survive boolean in the function?

Answer (score 0):

the variables in a function are local variables and `age` is outside the function.
Hence, you need to use the `global` keyword in the function as

```py
    def survival():
        global age
        global survive
        if age%2 == 0:
            survive = False
        else:
            survive = True
```

secondly, you are taking age input as a string and this will give you a `Type error` when you use an operator. You need to typecast it into an integer
`age=int(age)` or `age=int(input())`.

Lastly, I would recommend you to pass the value  in the function as @juanpa.arrivillaga said:

```py
    def survival():
        age=int(input())
        survive=False
```

or

```py
    def survival(age,survive=False):
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this chunk of your code:

```
survive = False   # Useless statement -- you replace the value on the following main-program line

def survival():
  if age%2 == 0:
    survive = False    # No need to set a variable; just return the Boolean value
  else:
    survive = True
    
survival()    # Make this line save a return value
```

To this:

```
def survival():
    return age%2 == 1

survive = survival()
```

Also, I think you need more practice with Booleans.  *Never* compare a variable to a Boolean constant: use the logical operators instead.   Where you have

```
if survive == False:
```

replace with

```
if not survive:
```

Even better, reverse the logic of your survival check:

```
def kill_me():
    return age%2 == 0

sudden_death = kill_me()

...

if sudden_death:
    print("Cthulhu rises through the floor; his presence destroys your very soul.")
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this is as below, hope it helps

```
age = int(input ("Type in your age\n"))
print("You're bored during quarantine and decide to go visit a haunted house alone. You 
visit the house, open the door, and walk in.")
print("You are in front of a creepy door in a hallway.")
print("What do you want to do?")
action = input ("Type: in, left, or right. Then click OK or press enter\n")

def survival(age=age):
  if age%2 == 0:
    return False
  else:
    return True

if action == "in":
  print("You choose to go in.") 
    if survival() == False:
      print("A monster pops out of the corner and eats you!")
    else:
      print("You turn the light on and realize that this is just an old bathroom. Gross.")
if action == "left":
  print("You choose to turn left.")
  print("A ghost appears at the end of the hall.")
  if survival() == False:
    print("The ghost chases you down and haunts your soul forever!")
  else:
    print("Your eyes mistook you, it was a spiderweb.")
if action == "right":
  print("You choose to turn right")
  print("A greenish light is visible in the distance")
  if survival() == False:
    print("The light gets brighter and brighter, and you realize it was the headlamp of a ghost coal miner!")
  else:
    print("You go to check out the light, turns out it's some old christmas lighting still plugged in.")

if survival() == False:
  print("May your soul rest eternally as you join the other ghosts at the haunted house.")
else:
  print("You survived your stay at the haunted house and apparently it's just a house.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit following in your code.

1. You input age as string. in Python, **input() returns string** value. you should convert the input value to integer. to do this you can use **int()** method.

   age = int(input ("Type in your age"))

or,

```
age = input ("Type in your age")
age = int(age)
```

2. You use age and survive in the survival function. But both are defined outside from the survival function. therefore use **global** keyword to use them in survival function. So, Code should be corrected as follows,

```
def survival():
  global survive
  global age
  if age%2 == 0:
    survive = False
  else:
    survive = True
```